# Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum from multible arrays

Tags: algorithm, search, combinations, subset-sum

How would you go about testing all possible combinations from a given set N, R, S of numbers so they add up to a given final number, where u can only use 1 number from each set?

A brief example:

Set of numbers to add:

```
N = {1,2,3,...}
R = {4,5,6,...}
S = {7,8,9,...}
```

Desired result: *All number that add up to X, so when **X = 12** the output would be*

```
[1,4,7]
```

Comment: For each pair (n, r) where n+r is smaller than X check if X-(n+r) is in S. If S in indexed this should be possible in O (n * n * log n).

Comment: @SaiBot With a hash, it is possible in `O(n*n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```js
var N=[1,2,3];
var R=[4,5,6];
var S=[7,8,9];

function xInNRS(x) {
  return N.forEach(n=>R.forEach(r=>S.forEach(s=>{if(n+r+s==x) console.log([n,r,s])})));
}

console.log(12);xInNRS(12);
console.log(13);xInNRS(13);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also store all, and then test for x, or print x:

```js
var N=[1,2,3];
var R=[4,5,6];
var S=[7,8,9];

var X={};

N.forEach(n=>R.forEach(r=>S.forEach(s=>{
  var sum=n+r+s;
  if(X[sum]==undefined) X[sum]=[];
  X[sum].push([n,r,s]);
})));

console.log("All Xs");
console.log(X);

console.log("Test x");
console.log(9,X[9]!=undefined);
console.log(16,X[16]!=undefined);

console.log("Combinations for x");
console.log(9,X[9]);
console.log(12,X[12]);
console.log(13,X[13]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```